# C#: Purpose of `using` statement with braces and anonymous object

Tags: c#, using

I know that in C# `using` with braces is used to ensure that the object is disposed like the following:

```
using (MyResource myRes = new MyResource())
{
    myRes.DoSomething();
}
```

Thus, this code is completely clear.
But I am reading a code where `using` with braces is used with anonymous instantiation. Here some samples:

```
public partial class FrmAuthenticate : Form
{
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkCredential writeCredentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        using (new NetworkConnection(IpPath, writeCredentials))
        {
            Username = txtUsername.Text;
            Password = txtPassword.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
using (new NetworkConnection(TargetProgramSldDir, writeCredentials))
using (new NetworkConnection(@"\\"+ this.TargetServerIp, writeCredentials))
{
    if (Directory.Exists(TargetProgramSldDir + @"\MyService"))
        Copy(TargetProgramSldDir + @"\MyService", backupDir + @"\MyService");
}
```

How are the anonymous objects used in the two cases? How is the created object of `NetworkConnection` used in the two codes? I don't understand what the purpose of the `using` statement of especially the first sample code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the created object of NetworkConnection used in the two codes?

It's just disposed at the end of the block.

I assume that what's happening is that the constructor will fail if the credentials are invalid - so in that case, the properties are never updated. If the constructor succeeds, the properties are updated and then the `NetworkConnection` is disposed.

One problem with the code as it stands is that the exception isn't caught - it will propagate up into the event loop, which hopefully has an exception handler attached - but it's really not terribly pleasant.

If this were code in a code-base I was maintaining, I'd try to refactor it to something like:

```cs
if (NetworkConnection.TestCredentials(IpPath, writeCredentials))
{
    Username = txtUsername.Text;
    Password = txtPassword.Text;
}
else
{
    // Report the error to the user
}
```